# Squares difference with gamma matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, dirac-matrices

$\newcommand{\fsl}[1]{#1\kern-0.4em\raise0.22ex\hbox{/}}
$How can I simplify the difference of squares $p^2 - m^2$ in order to
obtain $$\frac{p^2 - m^2}{\fsl{p} + m} = \fsl{p} - m~?$$  (where $\fsl{p}=\gamma^\mu p_\mu$ ). It is not a simple
squares difference because the denominator involves a gamma matrix in
the slash notation, so how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\fsl}[1]{#1\kern-0.4em\raise0.22ex\hbox{/}}
$Observe that

$$ (\fsl{p}-m)(\fsl{p}+m)=\fsl{p}\,\fsl{p}-m^2=p^2-m^2$$

since $\fsl{p}\,\fsl{p}=p^2$. Therefore, multiplying both members on the right by $(\fsl{p}+m)^{-1}$, you get

$$\fsl{p}-m=(p^2-m^2)(\fsl{p}+m)^{-1}$$

Now, $p^2-m^2$ is a number, therefore it commutes with the matrix $(\fsl{p}+m)^{-1}$ and you can write unambiguously

$$\fsl{p}-m=\frac{p^2-m^2}{\fsl{p}+m}$$

where the fraction is to be understood in the sense of the inverse element. The other way round, you just write

$$\frac{p^2-m^2}{\fsl{p}+m}=(p^2-m^2)(\fsl{p}+m)^{-1}=(\fsl{p}-m)(\fsl{p}+m)(\fsl{p}+m)^{-1}=\fsl{p}-m$$